# Run docker on read-only filesystem

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I like to run docker on a read-only filesystem. How is this possible?

The reason for this is that my machine is a Rasperry Pi and it is likely to lose power. I've set up the machine with overlayfs which woks fine so far. But when I start the docker daemon I get the

```
'overlay2' is not supported over overlayfs"
```

message. Any chance to still make it work?

EDIT: I've found out that I could mount just the /var/lib/docker/overlay2 folder on a tmpfs. But that would require too much ram as I would have to download all images (to ram) on reboot.